# Joi validate a string based on empty or non-empty values

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, mongoose-schema, joi

I have the below Joi validation for a field called store_type

```
store_type: Joi.string().valid(...Object.values(storeTypes))
 .error(() => ({
    message: `Store Type must be one of: ${Object.values(storeTypes).join(', ')}`,
 })).default(storeTypes.aaa),
```

wherein storeTypes is defined as

```
storeTypes: {
 aaa: 'AAA',
 bbb: 'BBB'
}
```

As per the above validation, what I expect is

- When I don't pass a value for store_type it should by default set the value as `AAA`
- In case if I pass an empty string or non-empty string then it should check if thats either `AAA` or `BBB`, if not then it should fail with the mentioned error

What changes can be done to the above code so that it works as per my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`error() must return an Error object`

- I tried myself and had to modify the [error](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#anyerrorerr) message with the custom error message that you want to add. you can also test it [here](https://joi.dev/tester/)

```js
    store_type: Joi.string()
      .valid(...Object.values(storeTypes))
      .error((err) => {
        err[0].message = `Store Type must be one of: ${Object.values(storeTypes).join(', ')}`
        return err
      })
      .default(storeTypes.aaa)
```

now you can access the error when you validate

```js
const { error, value } = schema.validate(inputObject)
console.log(error.details[0].message)
```

- or you can return an `Error` object

```js
store_type: Joi.string()
      .valid(...Object.values(storeTypes))
      .error(() => new Error(`Store Type must be one of: ${Object.values(storeTypes).join(', ')}`))
      .default(storeTypes.aaa)
```

and access the error like

```js
const { error, value } = schema.validate(inputObject)
console.log(error.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer @cmgchess
Actually the below snippet worked for me

```
store_type: Joi.string().allow('').valid(...Object.values(storeTypes))
          .default(storeTypes.aaa)
          .error(() => ({
            message: `Store Type must be one of: ${Object.values(storeTypes).join(', ')}`,
          }))
```

Comment: hmm for some reason it throws error `error() must return an Error object` for me. maybe i missed something